# Convert REACT js Component into an HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a static React component, which is pieces of information from a database.

I would like to create a function, so when the user clicks on a button, it will download the React component as an HTML file.

In other words, I would like to allow the user to download the HTML code that we can see when we click on Inspect ---> Elements in the browser.

Comment: This may have nothing to do with React, if all you are serving back is HTML. Please clarify with examples what happens when you query the DOM and serve resulting escaped HTML to the user?

Comment: Have you tried reading the base elements innerHTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main pieces are:

- serializing the component DOM tree as HTML using [`Element.outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) (or [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) if you're sure that's what you want) on a [`ref`](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)
- creating a [`File`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) from the HTML
- initiating the download of the `File`

Here's an example of how you could do it (adjust to your needs):

> Note that, unfortunately, Stack Overflow doesn't set [`allow-downloads` on the `sandbox` attribute of the iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe#attr-sandbox) used to render the live snippet demo (so the actual download won't happen when you click a button). Copy + paste this example into an HTML file and run in a local dev server to see it working.

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.16.8/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset('tsx', {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets['typescript'], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

const {useRef} = React;

function createHTMLFile (fileName: string, html: string): File {
  return new File([html], fileName, {type: 'text/html'});
}

function saveFile (file: File): void {
  const oUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.style.setProperty('display', 'none');
  a.href = oUrl;
  a.download = file.name;
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.click();
  a.remove();
  // 10s is arbitrary, but is more than enough for the user to download the HTML
  // even if they're preseneted with a download confirmation prompt by their
  // browser:
  const delay = 10_000;
  // the important part is that you clean up the object URL so that you don't
  // leak memory for every click (since they aren't garbage collected)
  setTimeout(() => URL.revokeObjectURL(oUrl), delay);
};

function Downloadable (props: { children?: React.ReactNode; }): React.ReactElement {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  const handleClick = () => {
    const div = ref.current;
    if (!div) return;
    const html = div.outerHTML;
    const fileName = `component.html`;
    saveFile(createHTMLFile(fileName, html));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Download as HTML</button>
      <div {...{ref}}>{props.children}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Example (): React.ReactElement {
  return (
    <>
      <Downloadable>
        <header>
          <h1>hello world</h1>
          <p>description</p>
        </header>
      </Downloadable>
      <Downloadable>
        <h2>a list</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>one</li>
          <li>two</li>
          <li>three</li>
        </ul>
      </Downloadable>
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwCYFMBmBDArgG3hgZzgCUUMBjGAGjiwJVLQF840oIQ4ByKMyrgNwBYAFCi0WAHaVgESXHK8MMFAAkAKgFkAMgDFgOFHAAUaAygByGECgBccAjCjBJAcxoALGCBz3HztwBKe31DRFE4OF4YLCh5SRQAdzhQlGMAbS8fAF0aM0MrGxoEGABPMDtuFQAPGAB6LJwuJkDhESZRcSkZOQcMADcUVJN8ytTguH6IYCRwkUjyOUc4CABVKBw4AF44VeJtADpFMhUAeQAjACsUSj3tU3NWiIUl-G24JAhyLBtJGCOlCoAKKGX4wYxcDBcJ7zOAYA6OUqGBEoGAABXYFVgpQhSGABDAOAwpS4NC4kjkKGhbUi8I8vDQ7zWGxpcIOn0SkhwEAwsx2owOkmsKFZn2+YIO5wgSFKBwwYAqkiQAGEPAYkMYMDDaUccMByABrYzatm8EAQQbG1l1OpwACMAAYiPi4VBzsAnBgoKUaOcsPAXebeHAYB4MPIUBSsK4PKxoCGPEY6CgoCGIB8IJzubyE0YNDpnja4ChBvJgIzQygScGwLx6AkVLNEh7YxgM1mebNFpIzFAQMpZPJaxwwPBzqVc8AoIXbed2Il6FBbM9u8tUESJztHQB9B17622ytwUCQWDh+BgL0Boih5RwUoQLAKQzh2hgXMrK43eB3Bzp2-wA+T6fJIXAwDOcAvgacA2EGE5oPGJYphO5B6oaJgEC45BGJWE5epGYFwK4XrnBgrhGIsOCGJQKBIIEzz0DA6igCgj7gsa2wAHy7PsBy8FMBooBc1y3PsxjMjggQ0OuxIwkwbRdNIMCDnAAAimZcp2GDnGExjDmABD2AgChqjgSC8JIAD89ikBQ-y2ZQFjSiKcAtDZfD2R5IIoGCcwLK8UToO8yaMAAPPm2iqcA-TeWCnHGJIuCSQpsKrvAYZKoYypodBOwcVs3EIM8-mSGu0XvAyRyxBZMCspE5YmAAhHi-SBIFMRxHVLylel3ibDsLUHGxKYRV1aWsOYhRGDsAAGizgJSfwHI0M1dQQAxDOYxjHMoahaHoW2jFNnh9YEJryZ0sLRLE8jGMVcChS1nH3ZEoV+jAMC9HI2X6gaWwIBlSBZTlTCcepHY5oQcARaFdTvZ9kjPbCkSvS1iAHBjCAMkwoMIPpBBHKZ5mRkwsNPfdZPRUjkRyaIQA)